# XML derivation in hive

Tags: xml, xpath, hive

We have a scenario to parse XML column into the hive.

1. Table 1 has 5 columns + 1 XML column.
2. We are creating a view using this table and applying XPath to derive and separate XML columns.

But the problem is, data retrieval is taking an out of time from this view (1000 rows in 10 mins) and this table has 500 million records.

Is there any way we can improve the performance.

Sample XML data:

```
<Metrics>
   <M Id="132">1.0000000e+000</M>
   <M Id="133">2.4000000e+001</M>
</Metrics>
```

we need to give different column names based on the ID value like:

```
,xpath_double (metrics, 'Metrics/M[@Id="1"]')                                                                AS totalConnectedTime
,xpath_double (metrics, 'Metrics/M[@Id="3"]')                                                                AS apneaHypopneaIndex
,xpath_double (metrics, 'Metrics/M[@Id="4"]')                                                                AS apneaIndex
```